# Does 'elseif' still exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I'm just learning ROR and I came across the if / else statements.  I also came across 'elseif' but my text editor (textmate) doesn't pick it up as a keyword, nor does the program run properly.

```
if name == 'Chris'
  puts 'What a lovely name.'
elseif name == 'Katy'
  puts 'What a lovely name!'
end
```

I'm using the book Learn to Program, which was written several years ago.  I was wondering if the 'elseif' was changed because, when I simply use 'else', it seems to function properly.

Comment: A simple Google search `ruby elseif` would have give you the answer that it’s actually written `elsif`.

Comment: I googled it but didn't even think that I was misspelling it.  Thank you for letting me know

Comment: @sawa I don't think you can use a comma after "because".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The comma after `because` is due to the fact that the part to follow: `when I simply use 'else'` is a parenthetical expression that is moved to the front of that clause. Not because it is after `because`. This is a very basic thing.

Comment: @Gumbo I Googled it and this question is the 3rd result. I always click on an SO result if its available. Your advice is now recursive :P

Answer (score 122, accepted):

It's `elsif`, not `elseif`.

Slightly confusing when you're new, probably.

Comment: why does ruby not show an error when someone uses ```elseif``` instead?

Comment: I'm the wrong guy to ask. On the other hand, I don't think many programming languages will tell you "Sorry, you got one of my keywords wrong, try again". I reckon the `elsif` form is one of those aspects of Ruby that comes from Perl.

Comment: Ruby guys can't spell?

Comment: I am new to Ruby and, coming from a C#, Java and JavaScript background, can honestly say that this sort of syntax weirdness disgusts me. Ruby and Rails creators have certainly made dog's breakfast out of this language.

Comment: This is a very counterintuitive departure from the norm. Thanks Ruby... super intuitive...

Comment: Spent awhile troubleshooting before stumbling on this answer. Not the most intuitive syntax change, Ruby developers. Ah well. Thank you @s.m.!

Answer (score 26):

Try with `elsif` (no second `e`).

[Source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#if-elsif-else_expression)

Comment: Cruel that this was the first answer ha!