# Create and use a function in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, web

I have a few lines of code that I would rather call as a function that paste in every time I need to call it.  I know how to do this in C++ but not sure if it works the same in Ruby or how it works.

```
    if op2_health < 0
      op2_health = 0
      @result = op1_name + ' Wins!'
    elsif  op1_health < 0
      op1_health = 0
      @result = op2_name + ' Wins'
    end
```

That is the code I want to use as a function but I don't know the function syntax in Ruby.  Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to just look at some Ruby docs? In any case, the correct approach depends entirely on how/where you want to use the function, whether it's shared across classes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function with `def`:

```
def my_function
  if @op2_health < 0
      @op2_health = 0
      @op1_name + ' Wins!'
  elsif  @op1_health < 0
      @op1_health = 0
      @op2_name + ' Wins'
  end
end
```

Then call it like this:

```
@result = my_function
```

I don't know your business rules, but are you sure, for example, that those conditions are mutually exclusive? Regardless, this should be the way to express your code as a reusable function--perhaps with some minor tweaks though for your situation.

Comment: That's not a function, that's a method. Functions (more precisely procedures) are defined like this: `my_function = -> { … }`

Answer (score -3):

I have identified the problem: Elsif isn't a word.

Comment: Everywhere I have seen elsif is correct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550407/does-elseif-still-exist