# I'm trying to implement advanced login like github but in session_helper an error rised

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def current_user
  if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  elseif cookies.signed[:user_id]
    user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to implement an advanced login like Github but in  `session_helper` an error rised.

> error is -- undefined method `elseif' for
>   <#:0x007fba76f98638>

But `elseif` syntax is correct. Who helps me?

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550429/2299040

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does 'elseif' still exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550407/does-elseif-still-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for `if`, `elsif`, and `else` in Ruby:

```
var = 10
if var == 10
  puts 'Variable is 10'
elsif var == 20
  puts 'Variable is 20'
else
  puts 'Variable is something else'
end
```

Make it `elsif` not `elseif`.